# How do I raise an error in Rust if a condition is not met

Tags: rust

I am very new to Rust so this may be a silly question but:

I have a function to take a string and return an `&Path` object, and I would like this to throw an exception if the directory does not exist.

```rust
fn parse_path(root: Option<&str>) -> Result<&Path, ???> {
    // Parse a string into a path object else use the default value
    let path = match root {
        Some(p) => Path::new(p),
        _ => Path::new(DEFAULT_PATH),
    };

    if path.exists() {
        Ok(path)
    } else {
        ???
    }
}
```

in Python I would just say

```py
if not os.path.exists(path):
    raise FileNotFoundError(path)
```

I don't know what the equivalent syntax in Rust would be. Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I've considered using `Option(path)` and `panic!` if a `None` is returned, but I would prefer to return a specific error so it can be handled outside of the function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```rust
Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::NotFound, format!("FileNotFoundError: {}", path)))
```

don't forget to import `Error` and `ErrorKind`:

```js
use std::io::{Error, ErrorKind};
```

learn more about [ErrorKind](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/enum.ErrorKind.html)